# RDLC grouping: header repitition to be avoided

Tags: rdlc

Need help with rdlc to obtain the below result

Expected result:

```
Rajveer
2.2
3.2
Surya
1.2
1.5
1.9
```

Actual result:

```
Rajveer
2.2
Rajveer
3.2
Surya
1.2
Surya
1.5
Surya
1.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're only displaying Detail rows in the table, something like:

[image]

Which gives results:

[image]

You need to set up a Row Group based on the name and display the name in a Group Header, then display the value in the Detail row:

[image]

Which gives results:

[image]